# MVC4 WebGrid in dialog hangs in IE and no pagination in Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

MVC4: I am new to using WebGrid with MVC. Code below produces WebGrid inside dialog, but pagination does not work in Chrome ( blank page displayed) and in IE : dialog with WebGrid shown , but IE hangs (seem to be doing something and then hangs, no chance to try pagination even).
What is wrong with my code?
Thank you
HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult MyReport (int id)       // get here on click in SelectList
{ 
      List<MyLocation> myl = MyLocation.GetAllLocations(31);  // static method in MyLocation model
      return View(myl);
}


public ActionResult MyLocationDetails (int id)
{ 
        LocationDetails ld = new LocationDetails();
        List<LocationDetails> model = ld.GetTestLocationDetails();  //model has 20 records
        return PartialView(model);    // MyLocationDetails partial view to be displayed in Dialog
}
```

MyReport.cshtml  View that should display dialog

```
@model IEnumerable<MyLocation>  

@Html.ActionLink("Location Details", "MyLocationDetails", null, new { id = 234 }, new { @class = "LocDetails" })

<div id="LocDetails-dialog"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#LocDetails-dialog ').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true
        });

        $('.LocDetails').click(function() {
            $('#LocDetails-dialog ').load(this.href, function() {
                $(this).dialog('open');
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

MyLocationDetails.cshtml

@model List

```
<div>
@if (Model != null)
{
    if (Model.Count != 0)
    {
        <div id="divLocDetails">
            @{WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: Model,
                               rowsPerPage: 5,
                               canPage: true
                               );
              grid.SortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
            }

            @grid.GetHtml(
                    htmlAttributes: new { id = "LocDetails" },                           
                        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
                        firstText: "First",
                        previousText: "Prev",
                        nextText: "Next",
                        lastText: "Last",                             
                        columns: new[] {  
                            grid.Column("city", header: "City",  canSort: true), 
                            grid.Column("country", header: "Country",  canSort: false)                 

                    }                      
                    )
        </div>

    }
    else
    {
        <label>No results</label>
    }
}
</div>
```

Comment: Your source doesn't seem to match your HTML. You call for `$('.LocDetails').click` but you have no element with that class in your source.

Comment: It matches @class = "LocDetails" in ActionLink. I was following code instructions I found online for creating dialog.